# Is date_parse_from_format() working properly in PHP? Related to Laravel 5 validation rules

Tags: php, validation, date, laravel, format

**The problem**

I've noticed that something weird is happening with "date_format" validation rule in Laravel. I'm using something like this in a form request:

```
'date_start' => ['required', 'date_format:d/m/Y']
```

and this rule is working and not complaining when the input is for example '01/01/16' rather than '01/01/2016'.

**edited**

Just my 2 cents here. As a work-around just to be sure the user input is a 4-digits year and a valid date, my validation rules is now:

```
'date_start' => ['required', 'date_format:d/m/Y', 'regex:/^[\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{4}$/'],
```

**end edition**

As per Laravel docs [date_format validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-date-format) it is using date_parse_from_format() behind the scenes. I have written a small script example like this:

```
<?php
print_r(date_parse_from_format('d/m/Y','01/01/16'));
```

and this is the result

```
Array
(
    [year] => 16
    [month] => 1
    [day] => 1
    [hour] =>
    [minute] =>
    [second] =>
    [fraction] =>
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_localtime] =>
)
```

As you can see there are no errors are it is accepting the year as year 16`. And here my question:

Following the official [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) 'Y' is 'A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits'. It explicitly says '4 digits'. I know that 16 is a valid year, basically year 16 of first century but I was expecting that Y will force the method to accept only 4 year digits or, at least, spit out a warning.

Any help? something to report?

Thank you

Comment: The year `16` is still a valid year (albeit rather a long time ago)..... the difference is that `y` will adjust a 2-digit year to the current century, whereas `Y` will accept it "as is" (as long as it's not after 9999-12-31)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I understand this but I think it is confusing since user will expect the year to have 4 digits. The problem is that in the case of the Laravel validator in my example your are force to pipe a regex rule to force the year to be a 4 digits number otherwise that rule is useless. Anyway I appreciate your comment. Cheers

Comment: I think that modifying the PHP docs to try and explain that it means a 4-digit or less year number would raise a lot more questions from people who don't realise that time started before 1st January 1000